# How to project WGS84 coordinates to calculate the distance in meters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, distance, india

I have geo coordinates from Google Maps which are WGS84 in decimal degrees for India. I want to calculate the distance between them in meters. Which projection should I use?

[image]

I use ArcMap 10.4.1.

Comment: In the reference systems folder of your ArcGIS install there is a shapefile called UTM that can guide you to the right UTM zone, from your coordinates you're likely to want UTM north projections... however if you want to use only one coordinate system to cover all locations within India perhaps somethig like https://www.spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/south-asia-india-albers-equal-area/ is what you're wanting or even Google Web mercator (EPSG:3857) if you're weighting convenience higher than accuracy.

Comment: You'd have to value convenience quite highly to use the awful distance values generated by Web Mercator over India.